# AttributeError: 'ProtoType' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR' [while running 'Send Payload to Pub/Sub/ToProtobuf-ptransform-48']

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm encountering an issue while using Apache Beam's WriteToPubSub transformation to send data to Google Cloud Pub/Sub. I'm receiving the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'ProtoType' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'

This error seems to be related to protocol buffers (protobufs), but I'm having trouble pinpointing the root cause. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with:

```
def convert_to_pubsub_message(element):
 if element is None:
    return None
 pubsub_data = {"table": element["table"], "payload": element["values"]}
 pubsub_message = {
    "data": json.dumps(pubsub_data).encode("utf-8"),
    "attributes": {}
 }
 print("Pub/Sub Message:", pubsub_message)
 return pubsub_message

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
# Read the JSON records from GCS or any source
  records = p | "Read JSON records" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(gcs_json_file)
  # Extract payload and table name from each record
  extracted_data = (
    records
    | "Extract Payload and Table" >> beam.ParDo(ExtractPayloadAndTable())
  )
  # Send extracted payloads to Pub/Sub
  message = (
    extracted_data
    | "Convert to Pub/Sub Message" >> beam.Map(convert_to_pubsub_message)
    | "Send Payload to Pub/Sub" >> WriteToPubSub(topic=pubsub_topic)
  )
```

Comment: Could you please upgrade the protobufs package by running the following command:`pip3 install --upgrade protobuf`. Once the upgrade is complete, please try again.

Comment: Yeah, I've upgraded it but still it's throwing same error.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion function has to produce a `PubsubMessage`, not a dictionary. Something like this:

```py
    def convert_to_pubsub_message(element):
     if element is None:
        return None
     pubsub_data = {"table": element["table"], "payload": element["values"]}
     pubsub_message = PubsubMessage(data=json.dumps(pubsub_data).encode("utf-8"))
     print("Pub/Sub Message:", pubsub_message)
     return pubsub_message
```

Check [the `PubsubMessage` documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage) for more details.

Comment: one example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/blob/main/Python/pubsub/write_pubsub_attributes.py